# How do you override the default JobLauncher? Spring Batch Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Are there any pure annotations based documentation for Spring? 90% of the docs I have seen are written for the xml implementation.

I am trying to override the default JobLauncher to be able to pass JobParameters, but any JobLauncher function I added to the below code was ignored and the default SimpleJobLauncher is run instead.

I would like to launch 4 concurrent instances of the same job with 4 different Job parameters. The parameters should tell the reader which directory to read from.

I am able to pass values for the directory using the @Value annotation, but that appears to only allow me to set a default value that will not change between runs.

I am not able to configure the job when I create it ("World" is completely ignored)

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);

    @Resource
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Resource
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Resource
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    ItemReader<Record> reader(@Value("") String directory) {
        return new ExcelReader(directory);
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor processor() {
        return new ItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobCompletionNotificationListener listener(){
        return new JobCompletionNotificationListener();
    }

    @Bean
    public Writer writer() {
        Writer writer = new Writer();
        return writer;
    }

    //Job Definition
    @Bean
    public Job job(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1("World"))
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(String directory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Record, Record> chunk(10)
                .reader(reader(directory))
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }
}
```

I am starting my application using

```
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

is there a better way to start the application??

Answer (score 0):

No news on the annotation documentation, but I found the answer to passing parameters. Since we aren't using an xml, we can use the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext instead and specify the top package. Then we use this context to get the default job launcher and pass parameters as we launch jobs.

```
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("package.names.*");
    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    Job job = (Job) context.getBean("testJob");


    Map<String, JobParameter> params = new HashMap<String, JobParameter>();
    JobExecution execution = null;
    JobParameters jp = null;
    try {
        params.put("directory", new JobParameter("testfolder"));
        jp = new JobParameters(params);
        execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jp);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update *transactionManager* bean if you want sb metadata to be persisted(Recommended).

```
@Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory(ResourcelessTransactionManager txManager)
            throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(txManager);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) throws Exception {
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExplorer jobExplorer(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) {
        return new SimpleJobExplorer(factory.getJobInstanceDao(), factory.getJobExecutionDao(),
                factory.getStepExecutionDao(), factory.getExecutionContextDao());
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return launcher;
    }
```